# Migrating a password field to Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql, passwords

I have used Django before (version 1.2) and generally I like it...  it is especially good at getting a brand new project up and running quickly.  But, in this case, I'm rewriting and existing system and moving it to Python/Django.  So, I already have a MySQL database that has a "users" table in it...  this table stores the user's password with the MySQL SHA1 function (no salt, etc).

As part of the migration, I'm going to fix some of the data modeling flaws and port to PostgreSQL.

I would really like to use django.contrib.auth, but I'm unclear what I need to do.  I have read the documentation, and know that I can separate the required user information and the "extra" information I have and put it into UserProfile.

But, how to handle the passwords stored in the MySQL db?

Has anyone handled this before?  What approach did you take?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what I did to get things working. I created a custom authentication backend. Note: I'm using the email address as the username.

Here is my code:

```
from django.db.models import get_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from hashlib import sha1

class MyUserAuthBackend(object):

    def check_legacy_password(self, db_password, supplied_password):
        return constant_time_compare(sha1(supplied_password).hexdigest(), db_password)


    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        """ Authenticate a user based on email address as the user name. """
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)

            if '$' not in user.password:
                if self.check_legacy_password(user.password, password):
                    user.set_password(password)
                    user.save()
                    return user
                else:
                    return None

            else:
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return user

        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None


    def get_user(self, user_id):
        """ Get a User object from the user_id. """
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then I added the following to settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'my_website.my_app.my_file.MyUserAuthBackend',
)
```

The suggestion from @Dougal appears to be for the next release of Django and was not available for me (I'm using 1.3.1). However, it seems like it will be a better solution.

Comment: This is a nice solution but a couple notes. You might want to use a constant time string comparison: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/utils/crypto.py#L34. You also might want to take the time to migrate the legacy passwords to Django format using set_password since you have the password at this point.

Comment: @Mark - I looked at the constant_time_compare function at the when I was developing my solution.  I guess I really didn't completely understand the point of it.  Also, excellent point about saving the password.  I will add it to the solution above.  Thanks!

Comment: constant_time_compare function is there to prevent timing attacks. The django-dev thread on its purpose is a good read: http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/8806aad29bc75ee0

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  I read the information and decided to updated the answer/solution with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably put it straight into the `user_password` field - see [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#passwords). Since you don't have a salt, try using the format `sha1$$password_hash`. I haven't investigated to see that it'll work with a blank salt, but that's probably the only way you're going to be able to migrate it without hacking `django.contrib.auth` or writing your own authentication backend.

Otherwise, you could just set an unusable password (the canonical thing to do is set the field to `!`) for users and point them to the forgot-password system.

Comment: just to clarify, Dougai is advising placing the password hashes into django, prefixed with the 6 literal characters "`sha1$$`", If my password was "password", in mysql the hashed password field would be `5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8` so you'd have to insert `sha1$$5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8` into the database.

Comment: I finally got back to this project and got a chance to test this.  I'm very said to report that this did *not* work.

Comment: @DavidS, this is presumably because the [relevant code does `assert salt`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L282). I think (though this is untested) the right approach is to make a custom password hasher that doesn't require a salt. That is: subclass `django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher`, set `algorithm = "sha1unsalt"`, copy `encode()` without the `assert`, override `salt()` to return `''`, add this class to `settings.PASSWORD_HASHERS`, and change the passwords in the DB to start with `sha1unsalt$$`. I think that should work....

Comment: @Dougal.  Thanks for the reply.  This looks like a good approach.  One question.  Is PASSWORD_HASHERS available in 1.3?  It looks like it is only document in the current "dev" branch and seems like something that is getting worked on for 1.4.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, that does seem to be new for 1.4; sorry, I just looked in the master branch. The relevant code for 1.3 [is here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.X/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L18) -- I don't see at a glance why a blank salt isn't working with that code, actually, which makes me worry that it might be something else causing the problem? You could try with the 1.4 alpha, though, and if your project won't be done before Aprilish you could just stick with that. (Or go live with whatever beta is current when you are done, which isn't recommended but would probably be okay.)

Comment: I don't know since when it is there, but in 1.5 there's already UnsaltedSHA1PasswordHasher in django.contrib.auth.hashers

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Django provide a hasher for unsalted legacy passwords. Just add this to your settings file:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
  ...
  'django.contrib.auth.hashers.UnsaltedSHA1PasswordHasher',
)
```